# why query unable to select specific id using mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am facing a strange issue using mysqli table. I have table in which there are some records. I am executing following query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 
EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM `games` 
  INNER JOIN `users_games` 
    ON `games`.`id` = `users_games`.`game_id`
  WHERE 
    `users`.`id` = `users_games`.`user_id` AND `game_id` = 10
  ) 
AND `users`.`id` = 10 
LIMIT 12;
```

In  `users_games` table there are `11` rows (`1 to 13`) for `user_id = 10`. The above query is working for all

```
`game_id` = 10 /* it is working */
```

When I try to execute `game_id= 1` then it is not showing record however there is row for `game_id= 1`.

Below it `users_games` table

[image]

Comment: Is the question PHP/mysqli related? If so please add the relevant code. You are using `game_id= 1` or `game_id= 10`?

Comment: You only show us the `users_games` table, but your SQL query queries two more tables, `users` and `games`. Please either remove these tables from your SQL query or show us the representative rows from these two tables. Also, please [edit] your post and poost the table rows as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: SQL tables/resultsets are **orderless** by definition .. Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`  is **meaningless** in MySQL and can result in different results even when the data is the same for each time you run the same query

Comment: user_id = 1 doesn't have game_id = 10  it has game_id= 1

Comment: Can someone kindly guide me why there is down-votes? I tried my best to explain the problem which I am facing

Comment: anyway, your query looks like it should work and return three rows from users_games (IDs 1-3, I think?) in the inner query - assuming there is a matching ID in the "games" tables, and then the outer query should reduce that to one row assuming there is a matching ID in the "users" table...but you haven't shown us that data, even though it's relevant to the question. Does the query work if you remove the LIMIT clause? Does the inner query work on its own? Lots of simple testing you could do to narrow down the problem.

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button on any question you can see the reasons for which downvotes are supposed to be given. Of course people may deploy other motives as well, you can't stop them. Maybe they noticed your rude comment earlier (thanks for removing it by the way :-)), or maybe they feel your question does not contain enough information (e.g. as per my last comment, there is a lot more you could do to make the situation clearer)

Comment: I would be a bit stronger than @ADyson and say the query works - so if it's not producing the result you expect then the data is not what you think it is.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for you comment. In other table data is same for like other rows. This problem is coming for only id=1 when I add new row with id=1 then it is working fine but when I removed the query does not works. At the end I can say if there is two rows with same id = 1 then the query is working fine

Comment: @P.Salmon I am sorry I could not got your point since my grammar is so weak. Can you kindly explain please. THanks

Comment: so again, do some testing to narrow down the issue. We can't test for you because we don't have access to your environment. As I suggested, try running the inner query only to see what it returns. And try running the whole thing without LIMIT, just in case that is interfering - as others have said, using LIMIT without ORDER BY doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you'd like some more practical help, try creating an online [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) which contains your data, so we can play with it. If you auto-generate some CREATE and INSERT statements from your current database you should be able to set it up pretty quickly.

Comment: @ADyson yes the inner query does not works when I execute separately  it is returning followin error `Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause'` also without `LIMIT` the query is working fine

Comment: well obviously you would have to remove `users`.`id` = `users_games`.`user_id` to test the inner query separately. I assumed you would realise that! If you aren't dealing with the outer query then that part is irrelevant, as well as causing a crash. Anyway, I would strongly suspect that LIMIT has something to do with it...do you understand why what you've written doesn't make much sense? If you're restricting the result to a single `user ID` from users table, then certainly you will only ever get 1 result max...why do you need to LIMIT it, do you think??

Answer (score 1):

Given these users

```
select id from users;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   6 |
|   7 |
|   8 |
|  10 |
|  12 |
|  14 |
|  15 |
|  16 |
|  17 |
| 999 |
+-----+
```

and this

```
drop table if exists games,users_games;

create table games (id int);
create table users_games(user_id int, game_id int);

insert into games values (1),(10);
insert into users_games values(1,1),(1,10),(10,1);
```

Your query

```
SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE 
EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM `games` 
  INNER JOIN `users_games` 
    ON `games`.`id` = `users_games`.`game_id`
  WHERE 
    `users`.`id` = `users_games`.`user_id` AND `game_id` = 1
  ) 
AND `users`.`id` = 10;
```

Produces

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 10 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is as expected. You could improve your question by including sample data as text in the question (as I have done in the answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is difficult to understand I mean what was the issue and where you have resolved it?

Comment: There wasn't an issue based on the data I created therefore your data cannot be the same as the model I created.

Comment: I really don't understand what exactly you talking about